# github example analisys of clock definitions for efr32fg14

Tags: embedded

in the link bellow we have I2C example  of efr32.
There are 3 components that i am having trouble to seehow they work together.

The only clock diagram i found is in page 281 of reference manual shown bellow.

i cant see where the CORE_FREQUENCY   goes?
why we enable HFLE LFXO I2c gpio ?
how its all allowing the final line i2cInit.freq = I2C_FREQ_FAST_MAX

I cant see the big picture behind it.
I'll be glad to have some intuition i could use to understand this mechanism.
Thanks.
https://github.com/SiliconLabs/peripheral_examples/blob/master/series1/i2c/i2c/src/main_efr.c

https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/efr32xg14-rm.pdf

1.

#define CORE_FREQUENCY              14000000

2.

// Enabling clock to the I2C, GPIO, LE
CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_I2C0, true);
CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);
CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_HFLE, true);

// Starting LFXO and waiting until it is stable
CMU_OscillatorEnable(cmuOsc_LFXO, true, true);
3.

i2cInit.freq = I2C_FREQ_FAST_MAX

Comment: Questions on stack exchange sites must stand on their own; they may not rely on external links for critical portions.  You will need to edit this so that it makes sense without following any links, though you can keep them for supplemental information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this MCU so this is based mostly on general MCU knowledge.

The MCU has a main system clock (this particular MCU calls it HFCLK).  The main clock can be sourced from one of a variety of inputs.  For this example they have chosen to base the main clock on the low frequency external oscillator (LFXO).  The function call `CMU_OscillatorEnable(cmu_Osc_LFXO, true, true);` sets `CMU_HFCLKSEL.HF` so that the Clock Switch block selects the LFXO signal to source the HFCLK signal.

Perhaps the board that this example was developed for contains a low frequency external oscillator that runs at 14 MHz.  And perhaps that is why CORE_FREQUENCY is defined as 14000000 for this example.

The main system clock feeds into many other clocks such as peripheral clocks.  Peripherals like I2C and GPIO need to be "turned on" by enabling the peripheral's clock signal.  The function call `CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);` likely sets `CMU_HFBUSCLKEN0.GPIO` to enable the GPIO peripheral clock, `HFBUSCLKGPIO`.

The I2C perhiperhal is not shown on page 281 but it is sourced from `HFPERCLK`, just like the `HFPERCLKTIMERn` and `HFPERCLKUSARTn`.  See the description of `CMU_HFPERCLKEN0` on page  346 for all the peripheral clocks sourced from `HFPERCLK`.  The function call `CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_I2C0, true);` likely sets `CMU_HFPERCLKEN0.I2C0` to enable the I2C peripheral clock.

It's not clear to me why the example enables the Low Energy peripheral clock, `cmuClock_HFLE`.  Perhaps that is not necessary.

All of the above simply selects the source for the main system clock and turns on the GPIO and the I2C peripherals.  All of this is necessary just to use the I2C peripheral.  (I2C relies on GPIO pins so the GPIO peripheral must be enabled to use I2C.)

Next the I2C peripheral needs to be configured.  And `i2cInit.freq = I2C_FREQ_FAST_MAX` is just a configuration option for the I2C peripheral.  The I2C peripheral has an output clock used for communications.  The author of the example code chose to use the fastest I2C communications clock rate, which is 400 kHz as mentioned in the comment.  Presumably, the call to `I2C_Init()` configures the MCU registers appropriately to select the fast I2C communications clock rate.  Perhaps `I2C_Init()` relies on CORE_FREQUENCY to determine the appropriate I2C register settings that result in a communications clock rate near 400 kHz.  You'd have to study `I2C_Init()` and the reference manual if you want to understand those details.

Comment: Hello KKRAMBO,i cant see core_frequency variable in I2C_init,how can i find it?
Another question is  regarding this line
 i2cInit.freq = I2C_FREQ_FAST_MAX
As you said we take a clock and prescale it over and over till it flows as water threw I2C peripheral.How can we demand certain number from I2C ?
if we choose a different external clock after prescaling we will get different clock in I2C.

Comment: [I2C_Init()](https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/efm32g/html/em__i2c_8c_source.html#l00353) calls [I2C_BusFreqSet()](https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/efm32g/html/em__i2c_8c_source.html#l00227), which gets the I2C input clock rate from `CMU_ClockFreqGet()` and then sets the I2C communications clock rate by calculating and setting `i2c->CLKDIV`.

Comment: Hello kkrambo,so I2C_BusFreqSet() can handle every source clock it will do CLKDIV accordingly to make 400Khz out of it.
Correct?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, I think that's correct.